# Difference between - and -​- in compiling options

Tags: miktex, options

In running MiKTeX

1. What is the difference between `-shell=escape` and `--shell-escape`
2. What is the difference between `-synctex=1`, `--synctex=1`, and `--synctex=-1`

Comment: Following GNU conventions, "long" options should be prefixed by `--`, in order to distinguish them from "short" options like in `ls -l`. However, all TeX distributions allow long options to be prefixed by `-` (and abbreviated as long as they remain unambiguous).

Comment: @Andrey: Is that a zero width non breaking space? I was considering doing the same, but now searching for `--` won't return this question, will it? I guess this would be a case for a request on [meta] to turn off auto-conversion of `--` to a dash, at least in titles. I haven't encountered it in post bodies, where it actually might make sense, except for code, of course. But since there's no code markup in titles ...

Comment: @doncherry: Yes, it's a ZWSP. It also seems that `--` does not work in search altogether.

Answer (score 13):

`-shell=escape` is invalid.

The correct syntax is the one starting with two hyphens. The versions with one hyphen (`-shell-escape`) often works too. But as Christian Schenk, the maintainer of MiKTeX, once wrote:

> Please note that the single '-' prefixes a sequence of single-letter 
>   options (aka short options). That is, if you specify `-unre`, you are 
>   actually invoking these options:
>
> ```
> --update-fndb  --print-only  --user-roots
> ```
>
> I would recommend, tha you always specify the "long options"
>   (prefixed by  two '-'). The  short options (one '-') are only for
>   backward compatibility.

Comment: For a second, I was wondering who _Christian_ was, then I think I remembered. Hope my edit is correct.

Answer (score 5):

With regard to question no. 2: `--synctex=1` creates a compressed SyncTeX file, while `--synctex=-1` creates an uncompressed one. (`--synctex=0` would create no SyncTeX file at all.)

Answer (score 3):

From the command line help:

```
-synctex=N Generate SyncTeX data for previewers if nonzero.
```

`-synctex` and `--synctex` are both accepted, so all three variants enable the generation of SyncTeX data.

`-shell` is an unknown command-line option and produces an error.

`--shell-escape` seems to be silently accepted. However with MiKTeX 2.9 it is not on the list of options any more. Packages like `epstopdf` need to be able to “escape to a shell”. In TeX this is done via the `\write18` feature. In MiKTeX it is only partially enabled by default to avoid security problems: only well known commands are allowed. You fully enable the feature by specifying `--enable-write18` on the TeX command-line.

Comment: @egreg Yes, that is my understanding too but as uli points out I'm not sure if it is documented

Comment: @uli I believe that MiKTeX 2.9 accepts `--shell-escape` as well as its traditional `--enable-write18`, for compatibility with TeX Live.