# mpgraphics: Unable to compile using MikTex on Windows

Tags: miktex, metapost, epstopdf

This is an example from mpgraphics package documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mpgraphics}
\begin{document}
\begin{mpinline}
draw (20,20)--(0,0)--(0,30)--(30,0)--(0,0)
\end{mpinline}
\end{document}
```

I am getting something like this:
[image]

I'm using:
- mpost version 1.504 (MiKTeX 2.9)
- pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9)
- MiKTeX EPS-to-PDF Converter 2.9.3275 (MiKTeX 2.9)

I compile using wrige using TexMaker and compile by means of:
`latexmk -e "$pdflatex=q/pdflatex -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode/" -pdf %.tex`

or

`pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -shell-escape %.tex`
(result is the same)

What am I doing wrong?

You can find the log file [here](http://pastebin.com/rstx2k4A). Example compiled by: `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -enable-write18 -synctex=1 -shell-escape %.tex`

Resulting pdf: [link](http://i.minus.com/1338321154/OVcSrH-bIYJ0eXRnLX19zg/dsowzQQW136Dp/tmp.pdf)

EDIT:
I tried to compile it by a command line. This is what I got:
[The whole folder with source and logs](http://i.minus.com/1338326518/MZPujPReykFqHlKOD-7yzA/dbtQSbTZCduhi6/tmp.zip)

Comment: You are using MikTeX. So you have to call `--enable-write18` ... see: http://docs.miktex.org/manual/pdftex.html or simple `texdoc pdftex`

Comment: I tried `latexmk -e "$pdflatex=q/pdflatex -synctex=1 -shell-escape --enable-write18 -interaction=nonstopmode/" -pdf %.tex` and it still does not work.

Comment: `--shell-escape` isn't available for MikTeX. Please test it with `pdflatex --enable-write18 --synctex=1 %.tex`.

Comment: How can `--shell-escape` not be avaliable when I do use it (without it my project wouldn't even compile)? Just tried `pdflatex --enable-write18 --synctex=1 %.tex`. No change.

Comment: I read that in MikTeX 2.9 shell-escape may work. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37570/difference-between-and-in-compiling-options/37573#37573 (Comment of @egreg). Whatever earlier MikTeX versions don't support shell-escape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in a previous comment, your example compiled without problem in my OSX box, so I was guessing the problem was in your Windows setup.

Looking carefully at your `_COMMAND_LINE_.txt` file, I noticed the following, in line 72:

```
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.004))epstopdf: -o: unknown option
```

Note the error at the end of the line. Your `epstopdf` program is refusing `-o` option, and thus it is not producing the pdf output. `mpgraphics` package issues a Warning, which somehow, instead of appearing in the standard output or in the .log file, appears in the final pdf. This is why your documment contains the strange text `mpgrahphics********` etc. (this could be considered a bug in mpgraphics implementation.)

Nevertheless, the problem is with your `epstopdf` program. `mpgraphics` package recommends a "recent" version of `epstopdf`. I don't know if the problem is that your `epstopdf` version is not recent enough or whether `epstopdf` is broken in Windows.

You can try to execute `epstopdf --help` in command line and learn which switch it uses instead of `-o` (which is for setting the name of the resulting `pdf`). Once you know this, you can hack the file `mpgraphics.sty` (search for the string `-o` in that file, in my version is at line 77), and change it appropiately.

Comment: `epstopdf` is a Perl script, so it should be platform independent. There may be a different version lying around that's used in preference of the "official" one.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In my version of `epstopdf` there is `--outfile=` instead of `-o`. I was able to change it in `mpgraphics.sty` as you suggested.

Comment: @VafaKhalighi Can you give a look to this?

Answer (score 5):

The problem as user JLDiaz said,  is because of the optional argument of `-o` of `epstopdf` program. I am sure that `epstopdf` program in TeXLive on any platform behaves the same. I tried this on Windows with TeXLive 2012 and it worked but it did not work with epstopdf that MiKTeX 2.9 provides. As for now there is no need to hack anything, your minimal working example just needs to be changed into:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mpgraphics}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\mpg@cmd@epstopdf}[2]{epstopdf \mpg@epstopdf@opts\space --outfile "#2" "#1"}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{mpinline}
draw (20,20)--(0,0)--(0,30)--(30,0)--(0,0)
\end{mpinline}
\end{document}
```

That is the epstopdf in MiKTeX 2.9 accepts `--outfile` whereas epstopdf in TeXLive 2012 accepts `-o`. I try my best to fix this in `mpgraphics` and release a new version of that to CTAN. But I do not think that one could implement an `\ifMiKTeX` conditional, so I think the only thing I could do is adding `MiKTeX` option to the package. But if you use TeXLive instead MiKTeX, you should have no problem with the current version of the package.

**Update:** The new version is now on CTAN. The TDS can be obtained [here](http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/install/macros/latex/contrib/mpgraphics.tds.zip).

Comment: Since `epstopdf` in TeX Live accepts the `--outfile` option, wouldn't it be better to use this one in all cases?

Comment: @egreg: Yes, you are right. I then change `-o` to ``--outfile``. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

On a Unix system I get the desired result with

```
latexmk -pdf -pdflatex='pdflatex --shell-escape --interaction=nonstopmode %O %S' filename.tex
```

Probably on Windows the quotes should be `"`, so I suggest to try giving Texmaker the instruction

```
latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex --shell-escape --interaction=nonstopmode %O %S" %.tex
```

If `--shell-escape` doesn't work you should try `--enable-write18`

---

You may try with `gmp`, which doesn't use `epstopdf`, instead of `mpgraphics`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shellescape]{gmp}
\begin{document}
\begin{mpost}
draw (20,20)--(0,0)--(0,30)--(30,0)--(0,0)
\end{mpost}
\end{document}
```

I tested it with the former call of `latexmk` and it seems to work.

Disclosure: I'm the author of `gmp`.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I tried to compile by command line. I posted result in my question,

Comment: I compiled your example under OSX, and got the desired result using the simple command line `pdflatex -shell-escape tmp.tex`. So if it doesn't work in Windows I guess that the problem is in the implementation of the mpgraphics package, which makes some assummptions which are not true for Windows. I'll try to dig into mpgraphics code and report my conclusions

Comment: @egreg It seems that hacking the `mpgraphics.sty` does the trick according to the user above. Is there a possibility to update the package `mpgraphics` to address this issue?

Comment: @azetina Ask the author of `mpgraphics`

Comment: @egreg The authors email or weblink seems not to be working. Hmmmmm