# What do these compile arguments mean?

Tags: latexmk, latex-workshop

I see that many people use these settings:

```json
"args": [
"-synctex=1",
"--shell-escape",
"-interaction=nonstopmode",
"%DOCFILE%"
```

Can anyone explain what these arguments mean and do?

Comment: Where did you see people using these setting? Why don't you ask there and those people? These are the only ones who can answer why they use these settings.

Comment: Combination of [compiling - What does --shell-escape do? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88740/what-does-shell-escape-do) and [tex core - Where to find official (!) and extended documentation for tex/latex's commandline options (especially -interaction modes)? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91592/where-to-find-official-and-extended-documentation-for-tex-latexs-commandlin) and [pdftex - What exactly is SyncTeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118489/what-exactly-is-synctex)

Comment: (the synctex one is also *slightly* covered in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37571/250119)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally see the manual page of `pdftex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex` for information about the engine options and the manual of your gui/editor/TeX runner for information about its features.

##### `-synctex=1` (or `--synctex=1`)

Do the basic synchronization between the editor and the PDF viewer. For information about the synchronization see the documentation of your editor and your PDF viewer. Note: Value 1 is not the only available value. The synctex manual explains other numbers (also depending on the features of the editor and the PDF viewer).

##### `--shell-escape`

Allow the TeX engine to run every application without any security check. This option is *not* recommended for foreign documents, you've not inspected before. Because someone could, e.g., delete directories or write other harmful code. For your own documents it is OK, because you should know, what you are doing.

##### `--interaction=nonstopmode`

Prevents TeX to stop on the first error. So TeX will try to continue, even if there are syntax errors in your code. This often results in several more errors than really exist.

##### `%DOCFILE%`

A placeholder for the (main) document file. This will be replaced by the caller and therefore is not a feature of the TeX engine but the system you are using with this configuration. You can find more information in the corresponding manual.